# print result before print a function?

Tags: php, function

I have a function with a loop foreach that prints a text line in each round and it adds 1 to a marker. E.g.:

```
function write(){
 $score = 0;
 Foreach ($array as $arr){
   echo "line 1";
   $score++;
 }
}
```

I want to print first $score and then text lines in the page where I will call that function.

How I can print before $score?

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. Do you want to print the value of score on each iteration? Like echo "Line: ".$score;

Comment: Your question is bit vague. Can you mention the expected output in your question that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function write(){
 $score = 0;
 $echo = '';
 Foreach ($array as $arr){
   $echo .= "line 1";
   $score++;
 }
 echo $score;
 echo $echo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo outside of the Foreach like this:

```
function write(){
    $score = 0;
    foreach ($array as $arr){
        $score++;
    }
    echo "Total score is: ".$score;
}
```

But if all you are doing is counting the number of items in the array then you can simply use this instead:

```
echo count($array);
```